# View missing after postgres restart

Tags: postgresql

When I create a postgres view like this;

```
create view sp_pool_relay_cnt as 
select hash_id, count(hash_id) as relay_cnt from sp_pool_relay
group by hash_id;
```

Then i restart restart using;

`sudo systemctl restart postgresql`

then my view disappears, how do i make it permanent?

Comment: Sounds as if you forgot to `commit`  the `create view` statement.

Comment: Is that true @a_horse_with_no_name? My views persist after a restart without having to `commit`.

Comment: @kometen Because you didn't switch your client to "autocommit disabled". There is guessing involved, but I cannot think of another cause for this phenomenon.

Comment: @kometen: If you create a view without using an explicit transaction, you don't have to commit. Otherwise, you have to. But a VIEW that has been committed, doesn't disappear without a DROP statement.

Comment: \echo :AUTOCOMMIT says it's on. i toggled it, still not saving.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe You are correct. I use psql without changing that particular value. Create views, tables etc. pasting into the terminal-window.

Comment: @rob Then you have to add steps how to reproduce the problem, because we cannot.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new test database and view, restarted the database and the view was available as expected, no issue with postgres. subsequently tracked the behavior to a startup script acting on the database.